# Is it possible to modify the templates used during creation of a C++ class by the Unreal Editor's Class Wizard?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am starting a new project and it will require the creation of many C++ classes. In order to keep the project organized I created coded standards that will keep methods and member variables organized using regions, nothing too complex. However, I do not want to have to modify every new class I make adding the separators(regions) by hand or have to copy paste from another file.
In unity it is possible to modify the template used in the creation of a new script, but i am having trouble finding the same information for the Unreal Engine. I am not using source and if it is required to do so I will probably just copy paste it for every class.

I tried searching online for information on the subject, but the results were less than useful.

Comment: template? What a template? c++ template? class wizard? What is a class wizard? What is adding a "region" ? Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: @Klaus I realize I did not mention it in the title that I am using Unreal Engine 4 to create c++ classes in my projects and I will edit it to specify so, but in the body I do mention I am using UE4 and the question is tagged with Unreal Engine 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify, create, and delete templates in Unreal Engine. Since you are not using Unreal Engine source, the templates are all located in the `C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_{version}\Templates` directory. If you are using Unreal Engine source, then the location will instead be `{engine-location}\Templates`. In these directories, you can modify the configs, the content, and the source code of each template. And of course, you can create new templates and delete existing ones.

If you do create a new template, then make sure that you do the following steps:

- Move the project that you want to make a template out of to one of the `Templates` folders mentioned above depending on the verison of Unreal Engine you have (source vs non-source).
- Update the ProjectName variable in your template's `Config\DefaultGame.ini` file.
- Copy any of the existing templates' `Config\TemplateDefs.ini` file to your template's `Config` folder.
- Modify the copied `TemplateDefs.ini` file, specifically the `LocalizedDisplayNames` and `LocalizedDescriptions` variables. These are the name and description of your template that show when the template is selected while trying to make a new project in Unreal Engine. Note that you may have to modify the other parts of the `TemplateDefs.ini` file depending on your project/template.
- Lastly, add pictures in your new template's `Media` folder. Add one picture named `{new-template-name}.png`, which will be the icon of the template and another picture named `{new-template-name}_Preview.png`, which will be be the preview of the template that appears alongside the name and description after one clicks on the template icon while trying to make a new project.

For more information, check out these resources:

- https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Basics/Projects/CreatingTemplates/index.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYM7iSh-uac